# Simple x86 Assembly Loop- Using PTR

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm learning x86 assembly and loops are very confusing to me.
For the prompt: "Write a program that uses the variables below and MOV instructions to copy the value from bigEndian to littleEndian, reversing the BYTE order.You will need to use PTR or LABLE to access just a BYTE of the 
DWORD element, and use LOOP (set ECX to 4) and ESI and EDI for indirect 
addressing."

My code displays 76993356

Should I be using PTR with bigEndian instead of just looping like this?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
    ; declare variables here
    bigEndian DWORD 12345678h
    littleEndian DWORD 0
.code
main proc
    mov ECX, SIZEOF bigEndian
    mov EDI, OFFSET littleEndian
    mov ESI, OFFSET bigEndian
TOP:
    mov al, [ESI]
    mov [EDI], al
    inc ESI
    dec EDI
    loop TOP
mov edx, littleEndian
call WriteHex

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: The only thing you have to do is think about where EDI points to initially and where each successive write to EDI is actually going.

Comment: By the way, you might find the `rol`/`ror` and `xchg` instructions useful.

Comment: your data is 4 byte long, and the first byte of bigEndian (offset +0) should go to the _>_>_LAST_<_<_ byte (offset +3) of littleEndian, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Very helpful!